# ¿Cómo calcular de un número su potencia?

Tags: python

Trato de obtener de un número su potencia.
Digamos que tengo el número `512`. De ese número quiero obtener otro número que elevado a `x` potencia (o sea `2⁹`), me de `512`.

Para realizarlo estoy utilizando `sympy` donde divido dos números y me arrojan un producto entero o en fracción, pero no un número con su potencia.

De la siguiente manera lo obtengo:

```
import sympy
P1 = input('P1: ')
P2 = input('P2: ')
d='/'
divi=f'({P1})/({P2})'
g = sympy.simplify(divi)
print(g)
```

Me gustaría saber si dividiendo `6**10` entre `2**2` me pudiese arrojar `2**8*3**10`, y si esto es posible, ¿cómo podría realizarlo? De antemano muchas gracias. Saludos!

Comment: siendo 2 la base: `print (math.log( 512, 2 ))` o `print (math.log2(512))` se le denomina [logaritmo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logaritmo)

Comment: Suponiendo que una división aleatoria entre 8¹⁰/10³  me da 134217728/125, ¿cómo haría que me diera 2²⁷/5³? Esa es la verdadera cuestión

Comment: Fácil, el 8 se descompone en `(2^3)^10` lo que, si aplicas teoría de exponentes, resulta en `2^10` que dará `1073741824` lo mismo que `8^10`. Y lo mismo para el otro número

Comment: En código cómo lo harías? Se me complica bastante el asunto

Comment: En un rato hago una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve bastante tiempo pensando y al final resulta que no es necesario utilizar logaritmos, puede que tal vez no sea lo más óptimo pero por lo menos funciona bastante bien. A su vez he dejado de lado el módulo `sympy` debido a que me ha sido necesario manejar cada operación de forma particular para no hacer la operación de potenciación al momento sino dejarlo para cuando se requiera, esto me permite aplicar la teoría de exponente y hacer todo de la forma en que esperas (aunque luego nos puede ayudar de mucho).

En principio solo necesitaremos importar el módulo `collection` para usar su clase `Counter` lo que nos ahorrará escribir un pequeño `for` para contabilizar unos datos.

Lo primero que hice fue separar la división en 2 partes, numerador y denominador, cada expresión debe se debe de manejar por separado. Las expresiones son, por ejemplo, `2^5` o `3^3`, por lo que, si en alguna de esas dos partes se tiene más de una expresión, por ejemplo `10^10 * 3^2` se deberá de procesar cada expresión por separado. Esta operación de procesamiento la realiza una función que identifica el número y su exponente en base a un simple `split("^")`

```py
from collections import Counter

num = "6^10"
den = "2^2"

def descomponer(expresion:str)->tuple:
    num, exp = expresion.split("^")
    num_proc = float(num)
    pot = 2
    div = []
    while num_proc>0:
        if not num_proc%pot:
            div+=[pot]
            num_proc/=pot
            continue
        else: 
            pot+=1
            if num_proc == 1.0: break
    return Counter(div), float(exp)
```

Esta función lo que hace es que dado una expresión `num ^ exponente` separa el número y el exponente y trata de simplificar el número para que quede como un `2` elevado y/o multiplicado a algo. En la lista `div` se almacena el número por el que ha sido dividido el número original, posteriormente se contabiliza las veces que aparece cada número en la lista lo que da origen a un exponente , es decir, si la entrada es `8^2` la lista `div` contendrá `[2, 2, 2]` ya que en la primera iteración se dividió el `8/2` quedando `4`, en la segunda iteración se divide `4/2` quedando 2 y por ultimo `2/2`, finalmente `Counter(div)` cuenta las veces que aparece cada elemento y retorna un diccionario `{2: 3}` indicando que el número `2` se repite 3 veces, que es exactamente lo que queremos, ya que si recordamos `2*2*2` es igual a `2^3` así que ya tenemos el exponente. Además de retornar el diccionario tambien retorna el exponente del número, ya que lo único que hace esta función es simplificar la base, el resultado de `descomponer("8^2")` es `Counter({2: 3}), 2.0`.

Ahora he tenido que crear una clase e implementar varios dunder methods para poder hacer las operaciones. Esta clase nos ayudará a manejar las operaciones básicas de potenciación, como lo es la suma o resta de exponentes en caso las bases sean iguales.

```py
class Number():
    def __init__(self, num, exp):
        self.number = float(num) if num not in [float, int] else num
        self.exp = float(exp) if exp not in [float, int] else exp
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if other.number == self.number:
            return Number(self.number, self.exp + other.exp)
        else:
            return self, other

    def __div__(self, other):
        if other.number == self.number:
            return Number(self.number, self.exp - other.exp)
        else:
            return self, other
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.number}^{self.exp}"

    def dist(self, number):
        self.exp *=number
        return self
```

Cada expresión evaluada será convertida a un tipo `Number`.
Para el caso de la multiplicación y división si las bases no son iguales se retorna los 2 objetos, ya que en el mejor de los casos se podrán simplificar en una división posterior, de lo contrario quedarán normal y no se resolverá la multiplicación.

Ahora lo que debemos hacer es descomponer el numerador y denominador, obtener los resultados y transformarlos a `Number`, pero recordemos que aparte de la simplificación de la base (que siempre será llevado a un operación de potenciación) se nos retorna el exponente, es decir que para la expresión `8^10` lo que se nos retornaría sería `(2^3)^10` por lo que deberíamos de multiplicar los exponentes, por eso definí el método `dist` para poder distribuir la potencia y obtener `2^30`.

```py
#descomponemos numerador y denominador
result_num = descomponer(num)
result_den = descomponer(den)

#obtenemos la simplificación de la base
numeros = result_num[0]
denominador = result_den[0]

#convertimos a Number y multiplicamos el exponente por el otro exponente
res_num = [Number(n, exp).dist(result_num[1]) for n,exp in numeros.items()]
res_den = [Number(n, exp).dist(result_den[1]) for n,exp in denominador.items()]
```

Para poder hacer un mejor manejo de la división se me ocurrió pasar todo el denominador al numerador pero obviamente con el exponente invertido, ya que una división se expresa como la multiplicación por el inverso de un número.

```py
#pasamos todo al numerador cambiando el signo
for num in res_den:
    num.exp = -num.exp
    res_num.append(num)
```

Finalmente solo nos quedará multiplicar todo el numerador y obtener el resultado, para lo cual cree una función que recorra la lista y vaya operando con las expresiones que tengan igual base.

```py
def mult_exp(expresion:list)->list:
    res = {}
    for num in expresion:
        n = num.number
        if n in res:
            res[n]*= num
        else: res[n] = num
    return list(res.values())

resultado = mult_exp(res_num)
print(resultado)
```

con esto nos quedará:

```py
[2.0^8.0, 3.0^10.0]
```

Recordemos que todo lo que está en la lista se esta multiplicando, si quieres puedes crear una función (o una clase) para poder representar mejor la expresión y quede mucho más bonito :D.

Comment: Está muy bien desarrollado el código y me imagine solo una fracción de cómo podría hacerse, pero no de la forma tan bien elaborada como lo hiciste. Solo un detalle, trata de dividir `6⁸/4¹⁰` y arroja `[2.0^-12.0, 3.0^8.0]`, cuando debería ser `3⁸/2¹²`, lo arroja alrevés, ¿por qué?

Comment: En realidad es lo mismo. Como dije, la división se expresa como la multiplicación de la inversa de un numero. Si tienes `a/b` es lo mismo que hacer `a*(b^-1)` y eso es lo que devuelve la lista. Retorna la multiplicación de `3^8` con `2^-12` (nota el signo). Si quieres prueba hacer la división `3^8/2^12` y luego haces la multiplicación  `3^8 * 2^-12` y verás que el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: También acabo de notar que mi codigo resuelve el problema de la capacidad computacional que posee sympy, dado que este siempre evaluará la expresión. En cambio mi código solo maneja strings y convierte a números cuando es necesario y siempre los números se tratan de reducir a lo más pequeño

Comment: Oh, ok es la multiplicación, creí que se dividía aún más, entonces el código en sí, se basa en la inversa, ya no se puede dividir más. Ya lo entendí, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

El módulo `simpy` tiene una función para encontrar los factores primos de un número.

```
from sympy.ntheory import factorint
n = 6**10/2**2
factorint(n)
```

Puedes acceder a la documentación de esta función [aquí](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html?highlight=factorint#sympy.ntheory.factor_.factorint).

Comment: Quiero agregar que esta operación es muy compleja computacionalmente y para números muy grandes es prácticamente imposible con una computadora convencional. De hecho los algoritmos de encriptación se basan en esto. Una computadora cuántica, sin embargo, lo puede hacer fácilmente.